# Point Quadtree regionsearch

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, quadtree

Based on this paper [Finkel and Bentley Point Quadtree](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Raphael_Finkel/publication/220197855_Quad_Trees_A_Data_Structure_for_Retrieval_on_Composite_Keys/links/0c9605273bba2ece7b000000/Quad-Trees-A-Data-Structure-for-Retrieval-on-Composite-Keys.pdf) i am trying to implement their datastructure but i dont really understand some points.

1. the function REGIONSEARCH and the procedure RECTANGLE_OVERLAPS_REGION

The procedure RECTANGLE_OVERLAPS_REGION takes 4 parameteres, namely `L,R,B,T`
but what are`LP,RP,BP,TP`? (the region boundaries?)

Everytime i compute this algorithm by hand i have the feeling that 1. i dont understand (or have misread) or 2. the algorithm is wrong, which i highly doubt.

So for Example if the `SE` Quadrant is considered number `4` then creating a new search rectangle (to search the subtree) with `XC,R,B,YC` and calling `se.REGIONSEARCH(XC,R,B,YC)` will create a new window in which the point of `SE` lies in. This will falsely add the point inside `SE` to the result.(Please consider the above link)

How does the region search in the above paper work?